# Error adding YafRay addon to blender 2.69

Tags: 13.10, graphics, blender

I can't install YafRay addon to blender 2.69. I go to user preferences, addons and when I select the file yafray.zip, blender throws an error message:

[image: Error message]

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I installed Blender 2.69 via ppa and it caused a lot of problems.

So, I downloaded the latest version of Blender and installed it manually.

Now It works very well and YafRay's error is solved.